# Count and group by on multiple coulmns

Tags: oracle

I have two tables as

```
SYSTEM
sys_id   version  state
(PK)
-------------------------
100        V12     A
101        V12     B
102        V12     A
103        V13     A
104        V13     C
105        V14     A

ENVNT
envnt_id  sys_id
           (FK)
----------------
1          101
2          102
3          103
4          104
5          105
6          106
```

Need to join this table to get the following results,

```
               total
version       sys_ids   state A  state B  state C
----------------------------------------------------
V12              3          2       1        0
V13              2          1       0        1
V14              1          1       0        0
```

I have started like,

```
SELECT st.version as version, count(st.version) as total sys_ids
FROM SYSTEM st
,ENVNT env
where env.sys_id = st.sys_id group by st.sys_id;
```

But I am clueless on how to imply this logic further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

```
select st.version as version, count(st.version) as total sys_ids,count(a),count(b),count(c) from
(
    SELECT sys_id,version,state,
    MAX(DECODE(state,'A',state)) as a,
    MAX(DECODE(state,'B',state)) as b,
    MAX(DECODE(state,'C',state)) as c
    FROM SYSTEM st
    group by sys_id,version,state
) group by version;
```

I have not include other table in query, because as per your data and required output there is no use of other table. If you need data from other table you may try with join as you have shown in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear do you really want to join tables ? Using your sample data the desirable result can be used without join:

```
SQL> with system(sys_id, version, state) as (
  2  select 100,  'V12',  'A' from dual union all
  3  select 101,  'V12',  'B' from dual union all
  4  select 102,  'V12',  'A' from dual union all
  5  select 103,  'V13',  'A' from dual union all
  6  select 104,  'V13',  'C' from dual union all
  7  select 105,  'V14',  'A' from dual
  8  )
  9  select version, count(*) total,
 10  count(decode(state,'A',1)) stateA,
 11  count(decode(state,'B',1)) stateB,
 12  count(decode(state,'C',1)) stateC
 13  from system
 14  group by system.version
 15  /

VER      TOTAL     STATEA     STATEB     STATEC                                 
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------                                 
V12          3          2          1          0                                 
V13          2          1          0          1                                 
V14          1          1          0          0
```

But if you joint tables you will get another result (not all SYS_ID from system table present in enevt table):

```
SQL> with system(sys_id, version, state) as (
  2  select 100,  'V12',  'A' from dual union all
  3  select 101,  'V12',  'B' from dual union all
  4  select 102,  'V12',  'A' from dual union all
  5  select 103,  'V13',  'A' from dual union all
  6  select 104,  'V13',  'C' from dual union all
  7  select 105,  'V14',  'A' from dual
  8  ),
  9  event(event_id, sys_id) as (
 10  select 1,          101 from dual union all
 11  select 2,          102 from dual union all
 12  select 3,          103 from dual union all
 13  select 4,          104 from dual union all
 14  select 5,          105 from dual union all
 15  select 6,          106 from dual
 16  )
 17  select version, count(*) total,
 18  count(decode(state,'A',1)) stateA,
 19  count(decode(state,'B',1)) stateB,
 20  count(decode(state,'C',1)) stateC
 21  from system, event
 22  where system.sys_id = event.sys_id
 23  group by system.version
 24  /

VER      TOTAL     STATEA     STATEB     STATEC                                 
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------                                 
V12          2          1          1          0                                 
V13          2          1          0          1                                 
V14          1          1          0          0
```

Isn't it a typo in IDs ?

Comment: If you see the post carefuly you will find author wants to join two tables. And I pointed above this is a problem. See care the first query.

Comment: This is a sample data. I am having more than 100 records. I am only aware of the state values.Need to get other values by joining on `env.sys_id = st.sys_id`

Comment: @tailorBird Does this mean status can have ANY value or are they restricted by some list/range ?

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov : State should be `A` or `B` or `C`

Comment: @tailorBird Then you can use any of advise from me or Emmanuel, just join tables before grouping / pivoting.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov: But I cannot do `select 100, 'V12', 'A' from dual` as I don't know the values except `State`.

Comment: If you don't want to exclude anything from SYSTEM table you simply should not join it with EVENT. Can you plese elaborate why do you need  to joint tables ? I dont see why you need EVENT there at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `SYSTEM` table and a `PIVOT` clause:

```
with SYSTEM(sys_id, version, state) as
(
  select 100, 'V12', 'A' from dual
  union all
  select 101, 'V12', 'B' from dual
  union all
  select 102, 'V12', 'A' from dual
  union all
  select 103, 'V13', 'A' from dual
  union all
  select 104, 'V13', 'C' from dual
  union all
  select 105, 'V14', 'A' from dual
)
SELECT version, state_a + state_b + state_c total_sys_ids, state_a, state_b, state_c
FROM
(
  select * from SYSTEM st
)
pivot (count(sys_id) for state in ('A' as state_a, 'B' as state_b, 'C' as state_c));
```

This gives the expected result:

```
    VERSION TOTAL_SYS_IDS   STATE_A STATE_B STATE_C
1   V12     3           2           1       0
2   V13     2           1           0       1
3   V14     1           1           0       0
```

Comment: Author initially wants to join tables.

Comment: This is a sample data. I am having more than 100 records. I am only aware of the `state` values.Need to get other values by joining on `env.sys_id = st.sys_id `

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why you would need a join here: you only use `version` and `state` from `SYSTEM` table.